# AWS Elastic Beanstalk and Github with same .gitignore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gitignore

I m using github for hosting my code and AWS Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my project. There is no any relation between them while deploying.

So I have too big compiled bundle.js files. Its automatically compiles in any code changes. Because of that we are getting too many conflicts with my team.

I have disabled them from .gitignore but when I deployed with: `eb deploy` ElasticBeanstalk doesn't track the bunle.js files as well.

So I'd like to ignore my files only for github but they should be tracked from eb when I use `eb deploy`.

Is there any solution for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Just create separate `.ebignore` file:

> You can tell the EB CLI to ignore certain files in your project directory with a `.ebignore` file. This file works like a `.gitignore`. When you deploy your project directory to Elastic Beanstalk and create a new application version, the EB CLI will not include files specified by the `.ebignore` in the source bundle that it creates.

[Configure the EB CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore)

Comment: Just trying this again, and it seems the current version of `eb` does not honor `.gitignore`. Just copying `.gitignore` to `.ebignore` allows to actually skip the files, as expected. Perhaps a bug, but currently the second paragraph is incorrect on the handling of `.gitignore`.

Comment: @EricPlaton Thanks, I've removed the second paragraph.